# Django complex annotations: is this possible?

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions, django-orm

I am trying to do something that may simply be too complex for Django's current ORM features. But, let's give it a try anyway.

First, here are the models I am working with:

```
class Location(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
  beverages = models.ManyToManyField(Beverage, through='LocationStandard')
  location_number=models.CharField(max_length=255)
  organization=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class OrderGroup(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return str(self.id)

class Order(models.Model):
  group=models.ForeignKey(OrderGroup)
  location=models.ForeignKey(Location) #elim this or m2m
  beverage=models.ForeignKey(Beverage)
  units_ordered=models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)
  order_delivered=models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
  timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Here is what I am trying to render in the template:

```
{{ location.name }}
{{ location.latest_order }}
{{ location.unfilled_orders }}
```

So, I need to list each location, the time of the last order placed from that location, and a count of the number of order_delivered=False.

I can successfully get the locations most recent order timestamp like so:

```
locations = Location.objects.annotate(latest_order=Min('order__timestamp')).order_by('latest_order')
```

but now I want to do a count of the order_delivered=False for that order. I am pretty stumped.

Any help for me?

Comment: `count=locations.filter(order__delivered=False).count()`?

Comment: I guess I could annotate this query then like so? `locations = count.objects.annotate(latest_order=Min('order__timestamp').order_by('latest_order'))`

Comment: will try tonight when I get home

Comment: What is `count` for you? In my comment is an `int`.

Comment: sorry, read too quickly, I can't do anything with only an integer, I need to know that that integer is related to the location somehow in the template, but I think I could use you approach with something like this: `count=locations.filter(order__delivered=False).annotate(undelivered=Count(order_delivered))` then `locations = count.objects.annotate(latest_order=Min('order__timestamp').order_by('latest_orde‌​r'))`

Comment: Ok :) whatever works for you. Hope it works.

Comment: "count" is a list of integers, one for each location ;)

Answer (score 2):

Does this do the trick?

```
locations = Locations.objects.annotate(
    unfilled_orders= Count('order', filter=Q(order__delivered=False),
    latest_order=Min(order__timestamp),
).order_by('unfilled_orders')  # If you like
```

The first annotation adds the `unfilled_orders` as a count of orders for that location where `delivered==False`.  The second, you already discovered, grabs the latest order's timestamp.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this. Please give edits if there are errors :)

Check here for more handy incantations:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

The `filter` argument to `Count` exists since Django 2.0.  You can accomplish the same with SubQuery Expressions in Django 1.11:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#subquery-expressions